# Comodo firewall: why an app set to "blocked" is in the "listen" state in network?

Tags: firewalls

Did I make a mistake, or is the Comodo firewall buggy?

I checked the blocked mode, it's supposed to block in/out requests.

(and by the way I don't understand why the "local address" is set to Adobe since the app that is supposed to be blocked has nothing to do with Adobe.)

[image: printscreen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The firewall blocks network traffic. Any process can be active and listening for network traffic regardless of what's going on with the firewall. It's like hoping for the phone to ring, but it never does.

If the firewall blocks traffic, then the listening process will never make any connections, but that does not stop the process from listening.

So, there is no bug and nothing is wrong. That process, if the firewall works, will simply never reach an 'established' state.

Comment: I can't upvote your question yet, (not enough reputation), but thanks a lot for your patience and your explanations.